# How to set ng-blur function name on controller and pass it to view

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to set, from my angularjs controller to my html view, the name of a function on the controller to be triggered.

I have this on my controller:

```
$scope.functionName = 'change();';
```

and in my html view I have this:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="{{functionName}}" />
```

but it doesn't work. I have an expression error, here is the error text:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax]
```

Comment: The parse sees you trying to bind the blur to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would not want to pass a function name to your view but instead just call the function on the controller directly.

In your controller:

```
$scope.handleBlur = function () {
  // do something here
};
```

And in your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="handleBlur()" />
```

If you do need to dynamically update what happens on blur, you can either have the handleBlur function include that logic in it or you could swap out the handleBlur function with a new implementation in your controller like so:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
function doSomethingElse() { ... }

$scope.handleBlur = doSomething;

$scope.updateHandleBlur = function () {
  $scope.handleBlur = doSomethingElse;
};
```